# Example for owned One-To-Many relationships in appengine JDo

Tags: google-app-engine, jdo

I'm new with appengine and JDo only i want an example for implementing owned one to many relationships

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check the App Engine documentation. It has [a section on one-to-many relations](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/relationships.html#Owned_One_to_Many_Relationships)

If that explanation is too short or unclear for you, can you please explain where you're stuck?

Comment: Actually it is too short and not clear, i only need a general example...for example a user profile entity that has as a field a list of type friend which is another entity contain the friends of that user,when I select the user I can also select the friends of that user only...i think it is general example or if you have better ideas that would be more general you will be welcomed